# ListBox Grouping - Bind Header with type does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am trying to get my objects sorted and grouped using the ListBox's Grouping feature.

The whole sorting part of the feature works great, but when trying to bind a property in the GroupStyle, it just doesn't work.

I followed an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2009/07/16/wpf-xaml-listboxes-with-a-grouping-capability.aspx) on MSDN and have done exactly the same procedure as the author, but it still doesn't work.

Here is the object which are in a List and then bound to the ListBox.ItemsSource

```
public class SearchResult
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ImageBrush image { get; set; }
    public Guid result { get; set; }
    public resultType type { get; set; }
}
```

It's the `type` property I want to group, which is an Enum and looks like this

```
public enum resultType
{
    Artist,
    Album,
    Track,
    Playlist
}
```

As for my XAML-code, here is the listbox itself.

```
<ListBox Width="400" MouseDoubleClick="SearchResultContainer_MouseDoubleClick" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="Transparent" Height="330" SelectionMode="Extended" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=srs}" Margin="0,370,0,0" x:Name="SearchResultContainer">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="50" Background="Transparent" Margin="5">
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Width="50" Background="{Binding Path=image}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Light" Margin="60,0" FontSize="18" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Light" FontSize="15"
                     Text="{Binding Path=type}"/> <---- Here is where I'm getting the issue
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
```

`Binding to the type property just doesn't seem to do anything!` And I've made sure the objects do have a value in the property.

And here is the last of the relevant code, it's where you add/remove the grouping:

```
    CollectionView myView;
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SearchResultContainer.ItemsSource);
        if (myView.CanGroup == true)
        {
            PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription
                = new PropertyGroupDescription("type");
            myView.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
        }
        else
            return;
    }

    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SearchResultContainer.ItemsSource);
        myView.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
    }
```

As I said, I followed the author's every move. 
Any suggestions would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `DataContext` of `GroupStyle` is [**CollectionViewGroup**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup(v=vs.110).aspx) which contains `Name` property to which you can bind to which will get you the value of property on which you grouped the items.

```
<TextBlock FontWeight="Light" FontSize="15"
           Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
```

Comment: Oh! I did not notice that. Thank you so much though!!